# API de suporte a PdfDocument (API 19) versão a partir da API 14

Tags: android, pdf

Estou necessitando implementar uma forma de gerar um PDF e enviar um e-mail como confirmação de um pedido. Percebi que foi adicionado na API 19 o [PdfDocument](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument.html) que já cria um PDF a partir de um objecto Canvas.

Gostaria de saber se alguém conhece alguma API de suporte que trabalhe de forma similar e que possa ser utilizado para versão anteriores do android (meu minSdk=14).

Vi outras bibliotecas que trabalham na geração de PDF mas de maneiras diferentes (não sendo criados a partir de objetos Canvas).

Essas outras bibliotecas de terceiros também tem o problema de serem pagos.

Answer (score 2):

É a primeira vez que ouço falar de uma biblioteca que gera PDF a partir do canvas de uma View. Não acredito que existam alternativas a essa biblioteca. Com alguma sorte, a equipe de desenvolvimento do Android vai adicionar esse recurso em uma próxima versão da biblioteca de compatibilidade.

De qualquer modo, existe essa biblioteca [aqui](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/) que serve para a criaçao de arquivos PDF. Os únicos problemas são que

1. ela não gera o PDF a partir do canvas como você quer,
2. a licença da aplicação não é gratuita e
3. a companhia desenvolvedora da biblioteca é conhecida por trocar o conteúdo de suas licenças deixando os desenvolvedores na mão.

Existe um tutorial de como usá-la no site do [Vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaPDF/article.html).

Existe também essa biblioteca [aqui](http://www.dynamicpdf.com/) que eu nunca usei e realmente não tenho conhecimentos para falar dela. Aparentemente não possui suporte total para android, mas você pode dar uma olhada se quiser. Só que licença também não é gratuita. Você pode ver um exemplo HelloWorld da biblioteca [aqui](http://www.dynamicpdf.com/Blog/post/2012/06/15/Generating-PDFs-Dynamically-on-Android.aspx)

Comment: Já tinha chegado a essas bibliotecas, mas nenhuma delas me atendia, inclusive pelo fatos das licenças. e também já estou criando o relatório em tela com Canvas, então essa API nativa seria uma mão na roda. já que não necessitaria de uma nova conversão. Inclusive tentem implementar minha própria API de suporte com base no fonte do [PdfDocument](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/8db45b8/graphics/java/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument.java) do android, mais tem recursos que estão apenas disponíveis dentro do package do android.

Comment: a iText PDF é realmente muito poderosa e simples de usar. Já utilizei em um projeto que tinha que criar e editar PDFs e a resposta foi excelente. Também indico sua utilização.