# Como cria arquivo PDF do ZERO (sem frameworks)?

Tags: java, android, pdf

Bem, estou analisando algumas possibilidades de gerar PDF's no Android (offline), e nenhuma é totalmente satisfatória, seja pela licença, funcionalidades, grande tamanho do framework, ou versão de suporte do Android (há o [PdfDocument](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument.html), que está disponível a partir da API 19 do Android, mas meu minTarget=14).

Então como estou necessitando até então é gerar um PDF simples, (quase que .txt, só texto, sem muita firula), só que uma exigência do cliente é que seja em PDF (clientes, sabem né). Então pensei em criar meu próprio PDF, a partir do source, só que pesquisei um bocado e não encontrei nada sobre templates do source de PDF's, por exemplo, como que tem que ser o header, como que se cria um paragrafo, etc. Só me aparece nas pesquisas frameworks, e mas frameworks.

Então gostaria de saber se alguém conhece algo e possa me mostrar um exemplo de criação do ZERO de um PDF, bem simples, com headers, um titulo e um paragrafo, e de bônus uma tabela (é a parte mais complexa do pdf que tenho que gerar), isso já estaria excelente.

E também como até onde conheço o [PDF é da Adobe](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_document_format), então talvez possa ter algum problema ou licença em relação a isso.

Comment: Fernando, deu uma olhada no iText? http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaPDF/article.html

Comment: @Guest, mas eu já até testei esse, só que ele além de ter um certo tamanho, [trabalha sobre licença AGPL](http://itextpdf.com/pricing), que não é o caminho que estou querendo seguir, já que, pretendia nem utilizar frameworks.

Comment: Andei procurando algumas aqui e, realmente, todas possuem algum tipo de licença. =( Não vi nenhuma de código aberto, para que você possa ver como funciona...

Comment: [pdfDocument](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/cd92588/graphics/java/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument.java) Talvez você possa observar o próprio widget do Android e tentar desenvolver o seu, não?

Comment: @Guest, já tentei mas ele `extends` de outra `class` nativa é se eu estendo dela, não tenho acesso a alguns recursos, internal (não visíveis para fora do `package`). Dai não consigo implementar minha biblioteca baseado na PdfDocument.

Comment: @Guest, a algum tempo atrás até postei [essa questão aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3029/api-de-suporte-a-pdfdocument-api-19-vers%C3%A3o-a-partir-da-api-14) mesmo no SOpt, mas não obtive sucesso e desisti da implementação.

Comment: isso é bem complicado. Até porquê seu cliente exige a API 14, mas a classe nativa do android só está disponível pra API19 (Patético) e ainda mais, todas as libs atuais são pagas! É... isso é bem chato. Eu vou estudar um pouco essas libs e, tentar, fazer alguma lib com uma licença totalmente open-source.

Comment: @Guest, sim, bem complicado, meus cliente já utilizam dispositivos com versão do Android 4.0 (API 14), atualmente desenvolvi para a primeira entrega os relatório em HTML, mais futuramente terei que migrar para PDF. Esperava que a própria Google fornecesse talvez uma API de suporte para versões anteriores, com uma copia do PdfDocument. O iText até já testei, e é bem bacana, funcionou bem nas minhas necessidades, só tem o problema da licença, que não é viável para o produto hoje.

Comment: Não tem como você tentar gerar os relatório para HTML e depois passar pra PDF?

Comment: Poderia ser uma boa até. Você gera o HTML no dispositivo, manda pra um servidor na WEB que vai receber, alterar para PDF, e mandar de volta já como PDF. O cliente não precisa saber disso... hahaha.

Comment: @Guest, até já vi, mas dai, é no servidor, e em meu caso tenho que gerar off-line, para mesmo off-line ele já ter acesso ao PDF, e poder enviar a uma impressora ou salvar em seus arquivos.

Comment: É. Realmente, complicou mesmo! Anyway, se eu achar alguma lib que seja útil pra você, eu mando aqui.

Comment: [PDFReader-Writer](https://github.com/bhavyahmehta/Pdf-Reader---Writer) Olha esse. Acho que *pode* ser o que você quer.

Comment: @Guest, vou dar uma olhada nessa lib e se der gol, posto um feed aqui. Valeu pela dica.

Comment: só um aviso, ela não é bem uma lib, está mais para um `app` que foi feito para isto. Acho que pode ser até melhor pra você, pois aí você pode fazer do seu jeito e com algumas alterações e etc. Boa sorte e abraços!

Answer (score -1):

No que eu percebi em sua pergunta foi que você quer criar um pdf, mas sua api mínima é *minTarget=14*, uma ajuda é copia o **source code** de [PdfDocument.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/8db45b8/graphics/java/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument.java) ou você pode fazer seu próprio código, mas pensando muito, percebo que você esta usando **JAVA N-IDE**, para que o projeto não fique muito pesado, recomendo que você copie apenas o necessário, alright!

vou te dar um exemplo:

```
package android.graphics.pdf;

public class PdfDocument {
    // agora você pode adicionar algo aqui, exemplo: as variaveis:
    private final byte[] mChunk = new byte[4096];
    private final CloseGuard mCloseGuard = CloseGuard.get();
    private final List<PageInfo> mPages = new ArrayList<PageInfo>();
    private int mNativeDocument;
    private Page mCurrentPage;
}
```

e se caso haver uma variável que use uma classe que não exista, você pode fazer a mesma coisa, mas lembrando, copie apenas o necessário e também o que vai ser usado por outras funções.

Comment: Me desculpe pessoal, era porque minha conta estava sendo usada por meu amigo, porque ele havia perdido a conta dele.