# Documentação para a criação de arquivos no formato PDF

Tags: android, pdf

Estou a algum tempo analisando bibliotecas livres para a criação de PDF para uso em aplicativos comerciais em Android, e até o momento não encontrei nenhum que satisfaça todas as minhas expectativas, de funcionalidades e licenças. Como pode ser visto [nessa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3029/2998) e [nessa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50595/2998) pergunta aqui mesmo no SOpt.

A melhor biblioteca que encontrei até o momento foi a [Android PDF Writer](http://coderesearchlabs.com/androidpdfwriter/), que tem capacidade de criar PDF básico e tem uma licença (BSD) adequada ao meu projeto, conforme consulta [neste excelente post sobre licença de software](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/76565/2998).

Apesar de fazer bastante coisa relacionada a PDF, foi projetado somente para criação de PDF simples, com textos e imagens.

**Então gostaria de saber/encontrar alguma documentação da lógica para se criar um PDF, para assim poder adicionar recursos a biblioteca?**

Como um exemplo de código da biblioteca citada, para se adicionar um texto ao PDF é implementado dessa forma:

```
public void addText(int leftPosition, int topPositionFromBottom, int fontSize, String text, String transformation) {
    addContent(
        "BT\n" +
        transformation + " " + Integer.toString(leftPosition) + " " + Integer.toString(topPositionFromBottom) + " Tm\n" +
        "/F" + Integer.toString(mPageFonts.size()) + " " + Integer.toString(fontSize) + " Tf\n" +
        "(" + text + ") Tj\n" +
        "ET\n"
    );
}
```

A primeira implementação que estou pretendendo é para a criação de tabelas onde a unica documentação que encontrei até o momento foi [essa](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/PDF6.html), que não consegui compreender complemente, e gostaria de algo mais detalhado, com por exemplo: estrutura da tabela, estrutura dos cabeçalhos, estrutura das colunas, estrutura das linhas, estrutura dos items. Para entender e poder implementar cada parte da tabela como um modulo.

Answer (score -1):

Bom amigo, verifique se isso pode te ajudar: 
um método é para você criar e outro é para você abrir.
segue o link também. http://javafordummy.blogspot.com.br/2013/10/how-to-create-and-display-pdf-file-in.html

```
 public void createPDF()
 {
  Document doc = new Document();

  try {
   String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/PDF";

   File dir = new File(path);
   if(!dir.exists())
    dir.mkdirs();

   Log.d("PDFCreator", "PDF Path: " + path);

   File file = new File(dir, "demo.pdf");
   FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

   PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, fOut);

   //open the document
   doc.open();

   /* Create Paragraph and Set Font */
   Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph("Hi! I am Generating my first PDF using DroidText");

   /* Create Set Font and its Size */
   Font paraFont= new Font(Font.HELVETICA);
   paraFont.setSize(16);
   p1.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
   p1.setFont(paraFont);

   //add paragraph to document    
   doc.add(p1);


   Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph("This is an example of a simple paragraph");

  /* You can also SET FONT and SIZE like this */
   Font paraFont2= new Font(Font.COURIER,14.0f,Color.GREEN);
   p2.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
   p2.setFont(paraFont2);

   doc.add(p2);

   /* Inserting Image in PDF */
   ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getBaseContext().getResources(), R.drawable.android);
   bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100 , stream);
   Image myImg = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
   myImg.setAlignment(Image.MIDDLE);

   //add image to document
   doc.add(myImg);

   //set footer
   Phrase footerText = new Phrase("This is an example of a footer");
   HeaderFooter pdfFooter = new HeaderFooter(footerText, false);
   doc.setFooter(pdfFooter);

   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Created...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

  } catch (DocumentException de) {
   Log.e("PDFCreator", "DocumentException:" + de);
  } catch (IOException e) {
   Log.e("PDFCreator", "ioException:" + e);
  } 
  finally
  {
   doc.close();
  }
 }      

 void openPdf()
 {
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/PDF";

  File file = new File(path, "demo.pdf");

  intent.setDataAndType( Uri.fromFile( file ), "application/pdf" );
     startActivity(intent);
 }
```

Comment: Olá, qual biblioteca está sendo utilizada para gerar esse PDF?

Comment: Fernando, ele usa a droidText

Comment: Mas essa [biblioteca utiliza licença LGPL v3](https://github.com/bullda/DroidText/blob/master/LICENSE), e como citei na pergunta necessito de algo mais permissivo, já que a [licença LGPL v3](http://escolhaumalicenca.com.br/licencas/lgpl-v3/), exige que o subproduto seja licenciado da mesma licença e que código fonte seja aberto. O que no meu caso não é possível, já que se trata de uma aplicação comercial de meu empregador.